# Qt 4.5 Focus doesn't work on QLineEdit

Tags: qt4, focus

I got an issue with a QLineEdit. Even if I set the tab order to start at this line edit, once the screen is loaded the LIne Edit won't get the focus automatically.

I've also tried with this two lines :

```
this->activateWindow();
this->lineEdit_password->setFocus();
```

But this has still no effect.
So maybe someone experienced the same issue...

Thanks in advance for your help, 
Boris

Comment: As an initial test, you could try overriding the showEvent() for the window. In the showEvent(), call 'this->lineEdit_password->setFocus();'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An other solution is to use a singleShot timer :

```
QTimer::singleShot(0,lineEdit,SLOT(setFocus()));
```

The focus will then be set once the application is free.
Boris.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much Krsna, overriding the showEvent() of the qwidget will work :

```
void OScreenLogin::showEvent(QShowEvent* e){
    this->activateWindow();
    this->lineEdit_password->setFocus();
    QWidget::showEvent(e);
}
```

The lineEdit gets the focus, I guess that an other widget had the focus set after these two lines.
Thanks again,
Boris